# Twitter sentiment analysis error code: KeyError: 'text'

Tags: python

I am trying to run a twitter sentiment analysis using AFINN in python. here is the section of code I am having trouble with:

```
# Create a list of the tweets ("text") only
text_only_list = [tweet["text"] for tweet in tweets_list]
# Remove digit and punctuation, and convert to lower case
new_list = []
for text in text_only_list:
    text = text.translate(table)
    text = text.lower()
    new_list.append(text)
```

And here is the error code I am receiving:

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-731d7bbe9420>", line 1, in <module>
    text_only_list = [tweet["text"] for tweet in tweets_list]

  File "<ipython-input-3-731d7bbe9420>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    text_only_list = [tweet["text"] for tweet in tweets_list]

KeyError: 'text'
```

Comment: the code I am using to get this error is:

text_only_list = [tweet["text"] for tweet in tweets_list]
new_list = []
for text in text_only_list:
    text = text.translate(table)
    text = text.lower()
    new_list.append(text)

Comment: Please edit that info into your original question

Comment: You can see the attributes with `dir(tweet)` and the keys of the dictionary with `tweet.keys()`. Apparently `"text"` is not among the keys.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means the `tweet` objects in `tweet_list` don't have a `text` attribute. Make sure the data looks like what you expect